# Глюк глассфиша?

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, jdbc, glassfish

Создал подключение к базе MySQL напрямую, минуя GlassFish, из NetBeans. SELECT получаю, вижу все таблицы, все заполненные записи. А из любого кода (разные проекты) строка:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from book");
```

возвращает ошибку

```
SEVERE:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Таблица/просмотр 'BOOK' не существует.
```

В тоже время "JDBC Connection Pools Ping Succeeded". В разделе "Серверы" > "GlassFish" > "Ресурсы" > "JDBC" > нужные источник данных и пул подключений у меня отображаются, всё прописано правильно. Создание экземпляров классов `InitialContext`, `DataSource`, `Connection`, `Statement` проходит штатно.

В `web.xml` тег `<resource-ref>` имеет вид:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/имя_базы</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Что ещё проверить, уже просто не знаю. Режим отладчика видит тоже самое - до строчки `ResultSet` - всё ОК. Есть ещё варианты диагностики проблемы?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знаю, что такое glassfish. Но из опыта могу дать идею либо попробовать выставить где-то текущую базу данных для соединения (или дефолтную ещё где-то), либо попробовать добавить префикс перед book

Comment: JDBC Connection Pools Ping Succeeded означает лишь то, что вы подключились к какому-то серверу БД, и вовсе не значит, что к правильному серверу. Проверьте хост и порт.

Отсутствие таблицы book опять же о том, что вы успешно подключились к указанной БД на указанном сервере. Но вот та ли эта БД? Опять же проверьте хост и порт, и также имя базы, с которой вы работаете.

Answer (score 1):

Факт подключается к базе данных по умолчанию(какая там в глазфиш встроена?)
Нужно определить или в глазефише или в дескрипторе развертывания приложения jdbc datasoure/connection, а потом ссылаться на него в resource-ref.
В вашем resource-ref нет отсылки на определенный таким образом коннект к базе, поэтому , я полагаю, используется база по умолчанию, в которой нет всех этих ваших таблиц.

resource-ref создаёт ссылку на какой-то ресурс.
resource-ref-name - имя этой ссылки.
связь ссылки с настоящим ресурсом и конфигурация самого ресурса задаётся в другом месте.

Comment: Почитайте эту заметку https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/datasource_resource_definition_in_java  
Там написано как определить подключение к базе данных и как его использовать в программе. Проще чем через resource-ref.

Answer (score 0):

ну попробуйте так "select * from название_бд.book"

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, это проект из курса по JEE от javabegin.
Аргумент метода lookup не совпадает с JNDI Name в настройках glassfish.

```
initialContext.lookup("jdbc/имя_базы");
```

в вашем случае.